# Hyperlink in ruby on rails not redirecting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a tab controller that contains two tabs.while clicking first tab(`tab1`) it will show a form field.I have a hyperlink in another page. what i want is when clicking the hyperlink it will show the form field contents of `tab1`.
Here is the tab controller am using

```
<div class="tabbable">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab-set">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Create</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">event</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
      <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
      <form field..........>
      </div>
          <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane"> l </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hyperlink using

```
<%= link_to "Create", "#tab1" %>
```

Comment: This doesn't feel like a Rails issue (and certainly not all the versions you've tagged), but more like a problem with your javascript (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<%= link_to "Create", "#", :anchor => "tab1"  %>
```